# What parameter use on "Data Time Format" of Export CSV function on Grafana to show the Unix Timestamp?

Tags: csv, unix-timestamp, grafana, influxdb

I have an influxdb database and I´m using it on Grafana to see the data.

I can export the data showed on the graph using the Export to CSV function on Grafana but the timestamp is converted to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ.

I would like to get the time in Unix Timestamp but I don´t know how to format the field Data Time Format on Grafana to use the Unix Timestamp.

What should I put on the Data Time Format to get the UNIX time instead of UTC time?

This are the parameters for the time field: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ

I expect to receive the time in milliseconds like 1554750812807 but I get "2019-04-08T16:03:47-03:00".